# GCC: don't include system information in shared object

Tags: gcc

I am building a simple library in C and compiling it with gcc

```
gcc -c lib.c -o lib.o
gcc -shared -o lib.so lib.o
```

If I inspect the shared object with objdump or xxd, the following appears:

```
GCC: (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
```

Is there an option to exclude this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove it after the fact with objcopy:

```
$ objcopy --remove-section .comment lib.so
```